# How to add PHP PDO drivers for Oracle to my Microsoft IIS Express 8 installation?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, iis, pdo

I'm currently using IIS Express 8 to run my PHP project locally, and Oracle SQL Developer for the database.  I need to add PDO support to IIS so I can access SQL.

1. Which driver(s) would be needed for this and where could I obtain them?

Answer (score 0):

Never used any of them, however the file should be in the ext/ directory of the PHP install.  You would just need to uncomment this line in php.ini and restart IIS (I assume):

```
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
```